# scanf("%s %s", buffer) not returning second string?

Tags: c, scanf

```
char buffer[128]
ret = scanf("%s %s", buffer);
```

This only allows me to print the first string fed into console. How can I scan two strings?

Comment: Increase the warning level of your compiler, and **mind the warnings**.

Answer (score 5):

```
char buffer[128], buffer2[128];
ret = scanf("%s %s", buffer, buffer2);
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to reuse `buffer` you need two calls to `scanf`, one for each string.

```
ret = scanf("%s", buffer);
/* Check that ret == 1 (one item read) and use contents of buffer */

ret = scanf("%s", buffer);
/* Check that ret == 1 (one item read) and use contents of buffer */
```

If you want to use two buffers then you can combine this into a single call to `scanf`:

```
ret = scanf("%s%s", buffer1, buffer2);
/* Check that ret == 2 (two items read) and use contents of the buffers */
```

Note that reading strings like this is inherently insecure as there is nothing preventing a long string input from the console overflowing a buffer. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf#Security.

To fix this you should specify the maximum length of the strings to be read in (minus the terminating null character). Using your example of buffers of 128 chars:

```
ret = scanf("%127s%127s", buffer1, buffer2);
/* Check that ret == 2 (two items read) and use contents of the buffers */
```

Comment: Why is this needed ? Can you not adapt scanf to accept two strings ?

Comment: This answer is perfectly correct if you want to store both strings in one buffer, processing them one after another. With two strings you have two pointers, two buffers, two memory allocations to clean up. I give +1.

Comment: @SimonOver: for each conversion specifier in the format string that doesn't have an assignment suppression flag on it, there *must* be a corresponding argument of the correct type.  If you have a format string of "%s %s", you *must* supply two additional arguments of type `char *`.  That's simply how `scanf` works; it's not sophisticated enough to know that you want to append the second input to the first in the same buffer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose two different locations for the first and second strings.

```
char buffer1[100], buffer2[100];
if (scanf("%99s%99s", buffer1, buffer2) != 2) /* deal with error */;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of words you want to read, you can read it as :

```
char buffer1[128], buffer2[128];
ret = scanf("%s %s", buffer1, buffer2);
```

Alternatively you can use `fgets()` function to get multiword strings .

```
  fgets(buffer, 128 , stdin);
```

[See Example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/C/Console/Usefgetstoreadstringfromstandardinput.htm)

Answer (score 0):

`#include<stdio.h>`

```
int main(){
int i = 0,j =0;
char last_name[10]={0};
printf("Enter sentence:");
i=scanf("%*s %s", last_name);
j=printf("String: %s",last_name)-8;
/* Printf returns number of characters printed.(String: )is adiitionally 
printed having total 8 characters.So 8 is subtracted here.*/
printf("\nString Accepted: %d\nNumber of character in string: %d",i,j);
return 0;
}
```